# рыба-текст lorem на русском в webstorm

Tags: webstorm

Подскажите как в webstorm сделать чтобы рыба-текст lorem был на русском?

Сейчас я набираю, например,

- **lorem10** ---> **tab** - получается 10 слов. *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, minus.*

Как сделать чтобы текст был на русском. **loremru** ---> **tab** - не работает почему-то.

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо сделать сниппет, и ключевым словом указать  **loremru**. [документация](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/live-templates.html)